# PHP Issue with date_create_from_format

Tags: php

What am I doing wrong please?

```
echo $_GET["time"] ;
$bookingDateTime = date_create_from_format("l, F d, Y g:ia",$_GET["time"] );
echo date_format($bookingDateTime,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

returns:

> Monday, September 21, 2020 6:47am
>
> **Warning**: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, bool given ...

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://3v4l.org/P9EWA

Comment: The `date_create_from_format` returns `false` if fails. Then `date_format` doesn't like that false value. (Probably problem with $_GET["time"] value)

Comment: Make sure you don't have any trailing space in `$_GET['time']`

Comment: var_export(date_create_from_format('Y', 'Monday, September 21, 2020 6:47am')); returns false. Is a non valid datetime value.

Comment: Once you get it working maybe this instead `echo $bookingDateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Comment: @sensorario: *date_create_from_format  Parses a time string according to a specified format* - you are specifying a different format from the datetime string, of course it's going to return false

Comment: 500 useless internet points says your input has some stray whitespace.

Comment: I go for Sammich's  "stray whitespace explanation",  especially in light of catcon's  "Can't reproduce" reply. So how do I find it in PHP???

Comment: `urlencode` is a quick & easy way to spot non printable characters, the percent encoding of “special” characters usually quickly tells you what you actually got there.

Comment: use `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_GET['time']));` instead of your all codes.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the issue: trailing non-printing characters at the end.
urlencode result:

```
Monday%2C+September+21%2C+2020+6%3A47am++%0A
```

No Idea what the ++%0A is all about! A null-terminated C string maybe?
Fixed by adding rtrim:

```
date_create_from_format("l, F d, Y g:ia",rtrim($_GET["time"]) )
```

Now all fine. Many thanks for the assistance.